# Remove Scrollbar from Textfields.bindAutoCompletion in ControlsFx

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

Is there any way to access and remove the Scroll Bar in JavaFX ControlsFX when building a Autocomplete Textfield with autoCompletionBinding?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using **CSS**:

```
.auto-complete-popup .list-view .scroll-bar:vertical {
-fx-scale-x: 0;
-fx-pref-width: 0;
```

}